# Getting the sum of total balance in C#

Tags: c#

I need to calculate the total amount. I have a sales invoice that looks like

[image: this]

How can I add up the amounts to display it in the total sales?

```
int orderNo = 234;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] {
                    new DataColumn("QUANTITY", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("UNIT", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("DESCRIPTION", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("UNIT PRICE", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("AMOUNT", typeof(string))});

while (dr.Read()) {
    finalam = dr.GetDouble(0);
    quantity = dr.GetInt32(1);
    unit = dr.GetString(2);
    description = dr.GetString(3);
    unitpr = dr.GetDouble(4);
    dt.Rows.Add(quantity, unit, description, unitpr, totalam);
    double sum = 0.0;
    Session["FinalAmount"]= sum += finalam;
}
 foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<th size='small' align='center'><b>");
                sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
                sb.Append("</th></b>");
            }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just a hint: Try to address the databasecolumns by name. If you ever need to add another column somewhere in the middle, you will have a lot of pain to maintain the read-procedure (had to do this on a 30 column table and all was addressed by the index).

Comment: **Use decimals for money, not doubles**.

Comment: I guess `finalam = dr.GetDouble(0);` should be `totalam = dr.GetDouble(0);`

Comment: thank you for the tip! Will get into that

Comment: But you should really store the correct types in the DataTable, not `string` for everytbhing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
double sum = 0.0;

while (dr.Read()) {
    finalam = dr.GetDouble(0);
    quantity = dr.GetInt32(1);
    unit = dr.GetString(2);
    description = dr.GetString(3);
    unitpr = dr.GetDouble(4);
    dt.Rows.Add(quantity, unit, description, unitpr, totalam);
    sum += finalam;
}

Session["FinalAmount"] = sum;
```

Simply you need to declare `sum` outside the loop, otherwise its value resets to 0 every time the loop runs. Likewise adding the variable to the Session should only be done once at the end of the process.

Personally I'd also advise you to store variables in your table as the correct types, rather than as strings.

Answer (score 2):

Let the database calculate the sum (using SQL `SUM` method), this is much faster than first pulling all rows into memory and then looping over them.

```
try {
    dbconnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader myReader = null;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS FinalAmount FROM [ordersTable] WHERE orderNo = @orderNo ", 
        con
    );
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@orderNo", orderNo ));

    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read()) {
        Session["FinalAmount"]= (myReader["FinalAmount"]);
    } 

    dbconnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    _logger.Error(ex);
}
```

Comment: He is fetching all the rows anyway for the datatable.

Comment: If this is the case, there is no benefit to calculating the sum in the DB. Go with ADysons answer.